# deactivate the impact of time zone to save LocalDateTime

Tags: angular, momentjs, jhipster

I use jhipster springboot and angular 7

I have a problem to send moment date from front to backend.

I have this example :

```
 var dateObj = '2021-08-5';
    var momentObj = moment(dateObj);
    var momentString = momentObj.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    this.student.startdateJc= moment(momentString);
```

the date is sending in this format :
[image]
in backend I have this code :

```
 student.setStartdateJc(studentDTO.getStartdateJc());
```

I found that the date before saving in database in java code (**studentDTO.getStartdateJc()**)
is **2021-08-4T21:00**

and the date in column after saving in database is **2021-08-4 18:00:00**

meaning the date is reduced 3 hours from front to backend and reduced others 3 hours to save in database

the column type in database is : **startdate_jc timestamp without time zone,**

and in java code : Student.java

```
 @Column(name = "startdate_jc")
    private LocalDateTime startdateJc;
```

StudentDTO.java

```
private LocalDateTime startdateJc;
```

and I have this config in **application.yml**

```
 jpa:
        open-in-view: false
        properties:
            hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
```

and the time zone of my server and the client is **(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh**

**I want to save in the database this date 2021-08-5 00:00:00**

**so deactivate the impact of time zone from front and backend**

Comment: Your code is very strange, why storing date as a string in student before JSON serialization? And also you strip time.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store it as Unix Time Stamp (just a number). Then you can easily convert it to any time zone related date format you want. I would recommend this approach as it makes it the most flexible.

Always try to keep it simple. And stepping over 3 TimeZones and solve this with code just to keep the timestamp human readable is too error prone and time consuming.

Another approach is to store it as a string, but please, don't do it.